# Localization of Noetherian and Artinian Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

**Theorem**: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $S\subset R$ be a multiplicatively closed subset. If $M$ is a Noetherian (Artinian) $R$-module then $S^{-1}M$ is Noetherian (Artinian) $S^{-1}R$-module.
I know the proof of the theorem, but my problem is that the converse is not true!
 The main idea of the proof as I understand is that there is a 1-1 correspondence between submodules of $M$ and submodules of $S^{-1}M$, but if that the case shouldn't the converse be true also?!
 Also can you please give me an example that the converse is not true. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ be a ring of polynomials in infinitely many variables over a field and let $M=R$. Then set $S^{-1}=R \setminus \{0\}$ so that $S^{-1}R=k(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ the field of fractions of $R$ which is a field of rational functions in infinitely many variables. So $S^{-1}R$ is a field and thereby a Noetherian and Artinian $S^{-1}R$-module. The issue here is that localization is, well, local. In the ring theoretic setting we can think of the localization at a prime ideal $\mathfrak p \subset R$ as creating a ring whose ideal lattice consists of the ideals contained in $\mathfrak p$. So for instance when we localize at $(0)$ we always get a field when the ring is an integral domain. There is the notation though of local-to-global properties in commutative algebra rings such that for every localization property $p$ holds then it holds for $R$. Unfortunately Noetherian is not a local-to-global property with a little bit of work one can show that every localization at a prime ideal of $\prod_{n \in \mathbb N} k$ is Noetherian, but the ring itself is not.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be an integral domain of dimension greater than 1. Then $A_{(0)}$ is a field, so in particular it is artinian. But $A$ is not artinian.

Comment: Concretely let $k$ be a field then $A=k[x,y]$ and $A_{(0)}=k(x,y)$.

Comment: @JacobSchlather can you tell me the difference between k[x,y] and k(x,y). and why the proof does not go backwards?!, and how about the noetherian case?

Comment: $k[x,y]$ is the ring of polynomials in two variables, $k(x,y)$ is the field of fractions in two variables.

Comment: @DamienL is it true that there is a 1-1 correspondance between submoduls of $M$ and submodules of $S^{-1}M$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110735/why-is-the-localization-of-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-still-noetherian)

Comment: @JacobSchlather is it true that there is a 1-1 correspondance between submoduls of $M$ and submodules of $S^{-1}M$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110735/why-is-the-localization-of-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-still-noetherian)

Comment: @JacobSchlather if $R$ is a field then $R[X]$ is not artinian, (because if so then $R[X]$ will be an artinian integral domain which is a field and thats a contradiction) if $R$ is a ring how can I show that $R[X]$ is not artinian.

Comment: @i.a.m Show that the descending chain $(x) \supset (x^2) \supset (x^3)$ does not stabilize.

Answer (score 2):

Submodules of $S^{-1} M$ are not in 1-1 correspondence with all submodules of $M$.  They are only in 1-1 correspondence with submodules $N$ of $M$ satisfying the condition: If $s \in S$ and $m \in M$, then $sm \in N$ implies $m \in N$ (equivalently, the annihilator of any nonzero element of $M/N$ is disjoint from $S$).

In the example given by Damien L , you can see an extreme case of what goes wrong: If $A$ is domain regarded as a module over itself, and $I$ is a submodule (ideal), then the annihilator of $1 \in A/I$ is $I$.  Thus in order to satisfy the condition above, $I$ must be disjoint from $S = A - \{0\}$, i.e., $I = \{0\}$.