# Show if $R$ is Noetherian, then $R_S$ is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noetherian, localization

Show if $R$ is Noetherian, then $R_S$ is Noetherian.

here is what I have read from somewhere else.
Suppose $R$ is Noetherian and $J$ is an ideal $R_S$.
Then $J=IR_S$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$.
Since $R$ is Noetherian, $I$ is finitely generated, say $I=(r_1,r_2,…r_n)$ 
Thus $J=(r_1/1,r_2/1,…r_n/1)$.
Hence every ideal in $R_S$ is finitely generated and so $R_S$ is Noetherian.

My confusion is how to get $J=(r_1/1,r_2/1,…r_n/1)$ from $I=(r_1,r_2,…r_n)$.
And I also confuse about the notation of $r_1/1$, what are they, are they suppose just be like $r_1/1=r_1$ ? Thank you.

Comment: For $r\in R$, the notation $r/1$ means the image of $r$ in the localized ring (under the usual homomorphism).

Comment: I think this was proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110735/why-is-the-localization-of-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-still-noetherian).