# Are all the subrings of $\mathbb Q$ noetherians?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples, noetherian

We know that a subring of a noetherian ring is not necessarily noetherian.

Indeed, if we take $A:=k[X_1,\ldots,X_n,\ldots]$ where $k$ is a field, then $A$ is a non-noetherian subring of $K:=k(X_1,\ldots,X_n,\ldots)$ (and $K$ is a noetherian ring because it's a field).

So the question is:

> Does there exists a subring of $\mathbb Q$ which is not noetherian?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming every subring contains the multiplicative identity.
Every subring $R$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ is localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at some multiplicatively closed subset. (Take $S$ to be the set of all denominators in the fully reduced representation of elements in $R$, then it is easy to see that $S^{-1}\mathbb{Z} = R$)

[The localization of a Noetherian Ring is Noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110735/why-is-the-localization-of-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-still-noetherian), thus every subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is Noetherian.

Comment: Nice answer. +1