# Show that the following localization is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization, noetherian

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(xy-9)$. Consider the maximal ideal $(x, y, 3)$. Let $A$ be the localization of $R$ at $(x, y ,3)$.

I wish to show that this is Noetherian, but honestly, I don't really know where to start or what to consider.

Any insights or help is appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z$ Noetherian? What about $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $\Bbb Z[x, y]$ is Noetherian
- Any quotient of a (commutative) Noetherian ring is Noetherian
- [Any localisation of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110735/why-is-the-localization-of-a-commutative-noetherian-ring-still-noetherian)

You can try to show each of these three points. The second point follows directly from the definition of Noetherian, along with a suitable isomorphism theorem. The first point isn't too hard, while the third point is a bit more tricky, so I included a link.

Comment: The first point follows the Hilbert basis theorem, right? Or is there a direct proof?